# ASP.NET 4.0 Website, want to put left menu in a file to edit from 1 file only

Tags: asp.net

I developed a website (I'm not a hard core programmer, but I can get by) using MS Visual Web Developer 2010.  I love it!  Stack people who responded to my 1st question recommended a new host, and that was a perfect recommendation.

Anyway, I have a navigational menu that I got from dynamicdrive on the left of every page.  Currently, if I want to change the menu, I have to edit 24 different pages (a lot of copying and pasting!).  I'd like to know if there's a way I can take the left menu, put it into a file (css? htm? Whatever the case ...), and then just put some type of  or  (??) type of tag there.  This way, when I want to change the menu for the entire site, I just have to change 1 file.

Here's a picture I put on photobucket:
[Picture of my left menu on my website (photobucket .png picture because I'm not allowed to upload pictures yet)](http://s1209.photobucket.com/albums/cc387/jdluski/?action=view&current=leftmenu.png)

Also, whatever recommendation you have, I'll do the same to the footer, with our legal copyright and social bookmarking links.

Thanks a bunch Stack people!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a [Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

Comment: Hey Hawkke, thanks a ton!  I followed your link, studied a little bit, then played around with a site.master for a little while, and finally figured it out!  I would never have thought to do this if it wasn't for you, so I truly appreciate you taking the time to read my question and respond -- it really, really helped me out, and now I'm understanding how to use MS Visual Web Designer 2010 a lot better.

Comment: Glad you figured out how to get it working. If you don't mind, would you please mark this answer as accepted so people know that your question has been resolved? Thanks :)

Comment: Absolutely.  Thanks again Hawkke.  It took me a lot of trial and error, but I think I finally have a decent handle on master pages and contentplaceholders, and such.